# Making multiple AngularJS Post requests to an Express Server? Server crashes on second post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-http

So given that I can't run these two post requests at the same time in my client, I'm trying to run the second post in the `.then` section of the first post. Which has always worked fine on my other projects. But for some reason when the second post request fires my server doesn't reply. When I check the console of the server, I notice it crashed and there's an error message (at the bottom of this post).

What could be causing this???

I have put breakpoints on the second post request in my server's code, and noticed the breakpoints don't even get hit. The server crashes before hitting  and giving me the option to continue.

Client Code (gets fired when user presses a button):

```
$scope.searchCharacter = function(){
    var request = {name: $scope.charName, realm: $scope.selectedRealm};
    //First post request
    $http.post('/searchCharacter', request)
    .then(function(response) {
        //sets some variables
        var id = 0;
        //Second post request
        $http.post('/helloworld', id)
        .then(function(response) {
            //sets some more variables      
            debugger;             
        });          
    });
}
```

Server Code:

```
//First post request
app.post('/searchCharacter', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    blizzard.wow.character(['profile', 'stats', 'items', 'statistics'], { origin: 'us', realm: req.body.realm.name, name: req.body.name })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.status != 200){
            res.send("That character doesn't exist! Please enter a valid character name.");
        } else {
            console.log(response.data);
            res.send(response.data);
        }
    });
});
//Second Post Request
app.post('/helloworld', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("hello");
});
```

Error message:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token #
>
> at Object.parse (native)
>
> at createStrictSyntaxError
>   (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream
>   12-7-17\Project\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:157:10)
>
> at parse (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream
>   12-7-17\Project\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>
> at c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream
>   12-7-17\Project\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
>
> at invokeCallback (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream
>   12-7-17\Project\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>
> at done (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream
>   12-7-17\Project\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>
> at IncomingMessage.onEnd
>   (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream
>   12-7-17\Project\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>
> at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
>
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)

Comment: It may be choking on the id as a number `id = 0`. Just for debugging purposes, try setting `id = {}` or removing `jsonParser` from `app.post('/helloworld')` and see if it still crashes.

Comment: I think that for your `helloworld` route you should use a route param instead of a json body, i.e., `app.post('helloworld/:id')`.

Comment: if you go for app.post('helloworld/:id') use req.params.id

Comment: @t.888 oh!!!! Now it works just fine. I made it an empty object and everything fired. Although thanks for the tip on using param. I didn't know that's how you passed params, and I've had to use jsonparser because I couldn't read req.body in my server functions without it. I'll try incorporating that into my code :)

Comment: You can run the requests at the same time. The nature of asynchronous functions is that they can be run concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.searchCharacter = function(){
    var request = {name: $scope.charName, realm: $scope.selectedRealm};
    //First post request
    $http.post('/searchCharacter', request)
    .then(function(response) {
        //sets some variables
        var id = 0;
        //Second post request (append id to route).
        $http.post('/helloworld/' + id)
        .then(function(response) {
            //sets some more variables      
            debugger;             
        });          
    });
}

//First post request
app.post('/searchCharacter', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    blizzard.wow.character(['profile', 'stats', 'items', 'statistics'], { origin: 'us', realm: req.body.realm.name, name: req.body.name })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.status != 200){
            res.send("That character doesn't exist! Please enter a valid character name.");
        } else {
            console.log(response.data);
            res.send(response.data);
        }
    });
});
//Second Post Request (get id from req.params.id)
app.post('/helloworld/:id', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    res.send("hello");
});
```

It appends `id` to the `helloworld` request, and defines a route `helloworld/:id` using `req.params.id` to pull the id out of the request.

Answer (score 0):

*Facepalm* I was using var id = 0 and passing it to my function without realizing it needed to be passed as either an object or a param. Thanks to those who commented!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted